# TargetException - PropertyInfo.SetValue failed

Tags: .net, reflection, propertyinfo, setvalue

I have a 'nice' problem here in which i spent to much time without any results. I've looked through google and so...without any success.

I'm using .Net 4.0 on the Desktop(Windows7-64Bit) and I'm using reflection heavily.

My current problem is that I have an instance of an own business object. I am using the PropertyInfo-object to have access to all properties of the instance. In general it works well, but sometimes I have properties which contains a generic list (or a kind of that (=> reimplementation of ObservableCollection<>). When I try to create a new instance of that property type and set the propertie's instance to the declaring instance, it fails with a TargetException.

```
PropertyInfo pi = instance.GetType().GetProeperty("Items"); // instance is a class instance of 'SomeData' class, Items is a property (ObservableCollection<T>)
pi.SetValue(instance, System.Activator.CreateInstance(pi.PropertyType), null); // the new instance (of pi.PropertyType) will be created without any problem, but setting in instance with SetValue failed with a TargetException.
```

I know that both (property and new instance) have the same time.

I tried that dozends of times, with more or less steps between the creation of the new instance and setting it to the property...without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Carsten

Comment: Please show the detail of the exception. Is the property writable? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: Is the property readonly?

Comment: Try with the first result of the following search on google: "how to create generic types with reflection"

Comment: No, the property isn't readonly and the both lines are directly from the source

Comment: Is the declared property type an interface (eg: `IList<T>`) rather than a concrete class (eg: `List<T>`)? If it's a class, is the class `abstract`? Does it have a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: If you received a TargetInvocationException, look at the exception details (specidically - the InnerException property). Usually, all required information is contained in the exception details.

Comment: @Richard. It is a concrete class, nearly like System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection (another implementation, but the same footprint). By the way, I took notice that the pi.GetValue() method with the same property also did not work. It crashed with the same TargetException. :( Thanks Carsten

Comment: @Carsten: Please post the full dump of the exception, including any `InnerException`.